# String control by variable at shell script

Tags: string, shell

I want to control string by variable at shell script.

**input data**

```
IDS_STR = 11 22 33 44 55 66 77
chk_id = 22
```

**expected output (echo ${handled_ids_str})**

```
22 33 44 55 66 77
```

**I tried method**

```
handled_ids_str=echo "${chk_id} ${IDS_STR}|cut -d '${chk_id}' -f2"
handled_ids_str=echo "${chk_id} ${IDS_STR}|awk -F'${chk_id}' '{print $2}'"
.....
ETC.
```

please your advice.
Thanks

Comment: (1) In your code, we don't see any assignment to, i.e., `SOURCING_IDS_STR`. (2) Run your code with `set -x` to see what's going on. (3) Setting a variable to the standard output of a command is done by `variable=$(command)`. Your code should produce a _command not found_ error. (4) If you paste your script into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), you should see several problems being reported.

Comment: How or in what way do you want to control the string with a variable?

Comment: I  edited. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved

```
af_awk=$(echo ${IDS_STR}|awk -F${chk_id} '{print $2}')
handled_ids_str=$(echo ${chk_id} ${af_awk})
```